# (SP 2013) Can sharing permissions be changed to suit a specific document library?

Tags: 2013, document-library, sharing

I'm a bit newer to SharePoint and couldn't find much on this area anywhere else. We have a sub-site that holds a document library we'd like to manage sharing permissions on.

Essentially, we want to restrict regular user's ability to share documents within this library and have a manager user share from there when needed.

I've heard that with SP Online you can manage permissions from Site to site, not in the fashion we need but it still exists.

So I was wondering if this even possible and if so could it be done without affecting the rest of the site?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are looking for **Breaking permission inheritance in SharePoint**.

Check below official documentation by Microsoft for the same:

[Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782).

**Additional Reference**:

[User permissions and permission levels in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I may have been a bit too vague, what I mean specifically relates to the ability to 'Share' a document with someone else. The documents we have shouldn't be shared internally or externally by anyone other than an authorised individual. 

We still want users to be able to view and contribute to these documents but not have the ability to share them unless authorised.